# Flutter Indexing Json Datas

Tags: android, json, list, flutter, mobile

I don't want to index the json like `(json["features"][0]` or `json["features"][1])`. How can I instead make this a list or something?

My code is below:

```
class Other {
  String title;
  double mag;

  String title1;
  double mag1;

  String title2;
  double mag2;

  Other({this.mag, this.title, this.mag1, this.title1, this.mag2, this.title2});
  factory Other.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Other(
      title: json["features"][0]["properties"]["place"],
      mag: json["features"][0]["properties"]["mag"],
      title1: json["features"][1]["properties"]["place"],
      mag1: json["features"][1]["properties"]["mag"],
      title2: json["features"][2]["properties"]["place"],
      mag2: json["features"][2]["properties"]["mag"],
    );
  }
}
```

json datas is here : https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your code:

```dart
factory Other.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  final features = json['features'];
  final firstProperties = reatures[0]['properties'];
  final secondProperties = reatures[0]['properties'];
  final thirdProperties = reatures[0]['properties'];
  return Other(
    title: firstProperties['place'],
    mag: firstProperties['mag'],
    title1: secondProperties['place'],
    mag1: secondProperties['mag'],
    title2: thirdProperties['place'],
    mag2: thirdProperties['mag'],
  );
}
```

Or use plugins like [this one](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) that generate JSON parser for your entity.

More information about how to work with JSON contains in [Official Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).